# Meaning of "Radial Separation"?

Tags: terminology

I'm reading conflicting uses of the term "Radial Separation."

On [this math forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20180303072651/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56487.html) it is implied to be "the distance between circles" as well as "the distance between the circles of the spiral".

A local ByLaw implies the meaning is distance between two places.

I'm looking for a definitive correct interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good luck. Here is my own interpretation, not definitive and possibly not correct:

Given some central reference point $A$, the radial separation between locations $X$ and $Y$ is the number of degrees (or radians, if you prefer) in the angle $XAY$.